# Regarding QUERY_ALL_PERMISSION permission

Tags: android

I was referring https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature
android official documentation for package visibility behavioural changes for app targets Android 11 and Higher.

If we need to query or interact with all installed apps on a device, independent of the components they contain. App needs to use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to to see all other installed apps.

Also, it is mentioned https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature intent filter based approach that your app might need to query or interact with a set of apps that serve a particular purpose, but you might not know the specific package names to include.

In regards to intent filter based approach, may be there is one loophole that I noticed while exploring the `<queries>` element if you add `android.intent.action.MAIN` as the `action` element in the intent filter to get almost all the installed apps without adding the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission since almost all apps would have this element in the AndroidManifest.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

**Question**
do we know if we follow this loophole  approach, will Google reject our app?

Comment: If you are a launcher app, that is exactly the type of query you need - that is the legit use case for that query. If you are not a launcher, then you don't need that.

Comment: I am having normal android app, not launcher app. 
will be still use this loophole approach? to get almost all the installed apps without adding the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

Comment: We are running a security app and we test for a list of screen-sharing apps installed and lock our app for the user if any are found as an anti-fraud measure.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @DurgeshPatel do you know the reason why setting <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> lets scan the 3rd party apps and other settings like  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> does not?